# Do I need to sign all emails now I have added DKIM to DNS?

Tags: email, dns, dkim

I have added DKIM to one of my domain DNS.

Does all outgoing email now need to be signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added a DKIM [ADSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices) record that says "all" or "discardable" to DNS, then you need to make sure all outgoing mail is signed.

If you have no ADSP record or your ADSP record says "unknown", then it's not necessary... but emails that are signed MIGHT fare better against spam checking software than emails that aren't signed.